# How to read/load zipped Shapefile on leaflet/react-leaflet in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, shapefile, react-leaflet

do anyone knows how to read/load shapefile (in zip format) on leaflet in reactjs?
In this project I had given a zipped shapefile and i want to show that data on Leaflet OSM map on react application.
Project Details
module/ library : react(18.2.0), leaflet(1.9.3), react-leaflet(4.1.0), shpjs(4.0.4)

Problem faced : I tried few examples but they didn't worked as they were of old versions.(example link : https://codesandbox.io/s/add-zipped-shapefiles-to-a-react-leaflet-map-e7cr0?file=/src/Shapefile.jsx )

Comment: I did not get the issue, it is already loaded on the map in codesandbox.

Comment: Yes @Elvin, but the example project runs with old libraries, dependencies, and modules. also reactjs was of version 16.
When I tried with the latest releases of the libraries and the code broke. I tried to solve the errors but it looks like react-leaflet, shpjs is not compatible with reactjs18.

Comment: Yes actually, it is an issue that happens to me before too for other libraries, react 18 still caused some issues on typescript, you can downgrade react typescript version to fix it, but it will not let you work for new features of React, which looks useless.

Comment: This the same demo written with the latest library versions https://codesandbox.io/s/add-zipped-shapefiles-to-a-react-leaflet-v-4-x-and-react-18-0-2-nlruc1. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I converted the shapefile into KML online and imported it to the application.